How can I merge specific dates into a date range in R
I am trying to integrate information on newspaper closures into a dataset of municipal elections in various provinces. The municipal elections data frame looks very much like this.
Each province holds municipal elections on fixed dates, but of course they vary by province. In each province there are multiple municipalities.
library(dplyr)

ab_elections<-seq.Date(from=as.Date("2001-10-01"), to=as.Date("2015-10-01"), by="4 years")
bc_elections<-seq.Date(from=as.Date("2001-09-15"), to=as.Date("2018-10-01"), by="3 years")
on_elections<-seq.Date(from=as.Date("2001-11-15"), to=as.Date("2019-10-01"), by="4 years") 
#turn into data frame
abdf<-data.frame(province=c("AB"), election_date=ab_elections)
bcdf<-data.frame(province=c("BC"), election_date=bc_elections)
ondf<-data.frame(province=c("ON"), election_date=on_elections)
#bind rows 
abdf %>% 
  bind_rows(., bcdf) %>% 
  bind_rows(., ondf)->df
#Now repeat for many different specific municipal elections on the same day in each provinces
purrr::map_dfr(seq_len(20), ~df) %>% 
  arrange(., province)->df
# df
# df<-data.frame(province=c("ON", "BC", "AB"), election_date=c(ab_elections, bc_elections, on_elections))
# df
df %>% 
  arrange(province, election_date) %>% 
  mutate(municipality=sample(c("Town A", "Town B", "Town C", "Town D", "Town E", "Town F"), replace=T, size=nrow(df)))->df
df %>% 
  arrange(province, municipality, election_date) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(n_candidates=sample(c(2:6), size=nrow(.), replace=T)) %>% 
  mutate(municipality_id=paste(province, municipality, sep="_"))->df
glimpse(df)

The dataset on newspaper closures looks very much like this. Note that I do have a key variable that links each municipality and each province. Some municipalities experience a newspaper closure in this time period.
These are documented in this data frame.
df %>% 
  slice_sample(n=10) %>% 
  select(-c(n_candidates, election_date)) %>% 
  mutate(closure=sample(seq.Date(from=c(as.Date("2001-01-01")), to=as.Date(c("2018-12-31")), by="weeks"), size=10))->closures
glimpse(closures)

Effectively what I want to do is to create a column closure or treated in the data frame df that indicates that those municipal elections have happened post-newspaper closure.
So, note that the dates for each newspaper closures in the data frame closures fall between the dates of each election in each province.
I can think of either somehow specifically merging the two datasets by the municipality ID or using a case_when approach where if an election in province Y and municipality x occurs after a date that appears in the closure data frame for the same municipality and province, then a 1 should be returned, otherwise a 0.

Check the lubridate package, especially the handling of intervals

What happens if the election took place after one newspaper closed but another was still open? What value do you expect? It would be helpful if you added your expected output to your post.

I'm comfortable just documenting newspaper closures on the assumption that there is simply less information available at T+1 than there was at T. People aren't in the business of opening up new newspapers to offset newspaper losses these days.

You can do non-equi join, maybe? I am not sure what should happen when when a closure what e.g. 2 election cycles ago. But perhaps something like this, which will give treatment = TRUE for any past closure:
left_join(
  df, 
  closures |> slice_min(closure, by = municipality_id),
  join_by(province, municipality, municipality_id, election_date > closure),
  relationship = 'many-to-one'
) |> 
  mutate(treatment = is.na(closure)) |> 
  as_tibble()


# A tibble: 87 × 7
   province election_date municipality n_candidates municipality_id closure    treatment
   <chr>    <date>        <chr>               <int> <chr>           <date>     <lgl>    
 1 AB       2001-10-01    Town A                  4 AB_Town A       NA         TRUE     
 2 AB       2005-10-01    Town A                  5 AB_Town A       NA         TRUE     
 3 AB       2009-10-01    Town A                  2 AB_Town A       2006-10-30 FALSE    
 4 AB       2013-10-01    Town A                  3 AB_Town A       2006-10-30 FALSE    
 5 AB       2001-10-01    Town B                  3 AB_Town B       NA         TRUE     
 6 AB       2005-10-01    Town B                  5 AB_Town B       NA         TRUE     
 7 AB       2009-10-01    Town B                  6 AB_Town B       2007-03-05 FALSE    
 8 AB       2013-10-01    Town B                  2 AB_Town B       2007-03-05 FALSE    
 9 AB       2001-10-01    Town C                  5 AB_Town C       NA         TRUE     
10 AB       2005-10-01    Town C                  6 AB_Town C       NA         TRUE     
# ℹ 77 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows



Would this work?
library(dplyr)

df |>
  left_join(closures, relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  group_by(pick(-closure)) |>
  reframe(treated = any((election_date > closure) %in% T))

Output
   province election_date municipality n_candidates municipality_id treated
   <chr>    <date>        <chr>               <int> <chr>           <lgl>  
 1 AB       2001-10-01    Town A                  4 AB_Town A       FALSE  
 2 AB       2001-10-01    Town B                  3 AB_Town B       FALSE  
 3 AB       2001-10-01    Town C                  6 AB_Town C       FALSE  
 4 AB       2001-10-01    Town D                  3 AB_Town D       FALSE  
 5 AB       2001-10-01    Town E                  4 AB_Town E       FALSE  
 6 AB       2001-10-01    Town F                  3 AB_Town F       FALSE  
 7 AB       2005-10-01    Town A                  4 AB_Town A       FALSE  
 8 AB       2005-10-01    Town B                  2 AB_Town B       FALSE  
 9 AB       2005-10-01    Town C                  4 AB_Town C       FALSE  
10 AB       2005-10-01    Town D                  4 AB_Town D       TRUE       
#...

